# How to get sum of all key values in array of objects without using any built in function

Tags: javascript

```js
var arrayOfObjects=[{value1: 50,},{value2: 100,value3: 600},{ value4: 300,value5: 700}];
var result = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
  var key = Object.values(arrayOfObjects[i]);
  var string = key[i];
  var result = result + (string);
  var keyValues = Object.values(arrayOfObjects[i]);
  var length = keyValues.length;
  if (length > 1) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var c = 0; c < length; c++) {
      var string1 = keyValues[c];
      var sum = sum + string1;
    }
  }
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either iterate against the values of `arrayOfObjects` or sum the one in the first index:

```js
var arrayOfObjects=[{value1: 50},{value2: 100,value3: 600},{ value4: 300,value5: 700}];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
   var innerLength = Object.values(arrayOfObjects[i]).length;
   if (innerLength > 1) {
     for (var c = 0; c < innerLength ; c++) {
       sum += Object.values(arrayOfObjects[i])[c];
     }
   }
   else {
     sum += Object.values(arrayOfObjects[i])[0];
   }
 }

 console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have array of objects, first convert array of objects to array by **map()** function and then convert arrays to 1D-Array by **ES-6 concat and destructuring**, finally iterate loop and calculate sum.

```
function sum() {        
        var arrayOfObjects = [{ value1: 50 }, { value2: 100, value3: 600 }, { value4: 300, value5: 700 }];
        var array = [{ value1: 50 }, { value2: 100, value3: 600 }, { value4: 300, value5: 700 }];
        result = array.map(Object.values); //convert array of objects to array
        arr1 = [].concat(...result); //convert to 1 dimension array
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<=arr1.length-1; i++)
        {
           sum = sum + parseInt(arr1[i]);
        }                
        console.log(sum);        
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but i said in the question no built in function